Jmeter response token for another request input parameter
How to get token from first request and use it in the second request
 HTTPSampler httpAuth = new HTTPSampler();
 httpAuth.setDomain( baseUrl);
 httpAuth.setPort(443);
 httpAuth.setPath("/permissions");
 httpAuth.setMethod("GET");
 httpAuth.setName("HTTP Request One");
 httpAuth.setProtocol("https");
 httpAuth.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, HTTPSampler.class.getName());
 httpAuth.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, HttpTestSampleGui.class.getName());


You need to add a suitable Post-Processor for this, for example Regular Expression Extractor.
Something like:
HTTPSampler httpAuth = new HTTPSampler();
httpAuth.setDomain(baseUrl);
httpAuth.setPort(443);
httpAuth.setPath("/permissions");
httpAuth.setMethod("GET");
httpAuth.setName("HTTP Request One");
httpAuth.setProtocol("https");
httpAuth.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, HTTPSampler.class.getName());
httpAuth.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, HttpTestSampleGui.class.getName());

RegexExtractor regularExpressionExtractor = new RegexExtractor();
regularExpressionExtractor.setName("Regular Expression Extractor");
regularExpressionExtractor.setRegex("(your-regular-expression-for-extracting-the-token-here)");
regularExpressionExtractor.setRefName("token");
regularExpressionExtractor.setMatchNumber(1);
regularExpressionExtractor.setTemplate("$1$");
regularExpressionExtractor.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS,RegexExtractor.class.getName());
regularExpressionExtractor.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, RegexExtractorGui.class.getName());

testPlanTree.add(testPlan);
HashTree threadGroupHashTree = testPlanTree.add(testPlan, threadGroup);
HashTree httpRequestTree = threadGroupHashTree.add(httpAuth,regularExpressionExtractor);
threadGroupHashTree.add(httpRequestTree);

More information: JMeter Command Line Overview: 5 Ways To Launch a Test

how to get the token if it is raw in the body response? without RegexExtractor

how to use the token in the second request?

if the token is "raw" and nothing else is present you can either use a wildcard regular expression like (.*) or switch to Boundary Extractor and don't provide any boundaries, just the desired variable name. The JMeter Variable can be referenced as ${token} where required

is Requests order is done by using ${token} ? i mean token request then another request
